# Finding the number of ordered pairs of integers (Discrete Maths)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $k$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $k\le n$

(i) How many ordered sequences of integers ($a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$) are there such that $a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$$\in $(1,2...n)

(ii) How many ordered sequences of integers ($a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$) are there such that $a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$$\in $(1,2...n) and $a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$ are pairwise distinct?

(iii)How many ordered sequences of integers ($a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$) are there such that $a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$$\in $(1,2...n) and $a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$ contain only one ordered pair?

(iv))How many ordered sequences of integers ($a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$) are there such that $a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$$\in $(1,2...n) and $a_{1}\lt a_{2}...\lt a_{k} $ ?

(v))How many ordered sequences of integers ($a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$) are there such that $a_{1}$,$a_{2}$,...$a_{k}$$\in $(1,2...n) and $a_{1}\le a_{2}...\le a_{k} $ ?

What i tried

(ii) pairwise distinct means that the integers can be group onto a pair with each pair being different from one another, thus we are group indistinguishable integers into distinguishable pair. Thus there are $k^{n}$ ways.

(iii) Ordered pair have got something to do with permutations so i think it is $k$ permutate $n$

(iv) While this part means that the integers must be arranged in order form the smallest to the biggest

Im unsure of how to do these questions. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) There are $n$ choices for the first element, and for every such choice there are $n$ choices for the second element, and so on up to the $k$-th element, for a total of $n^k$.

(ii) There are $n$ choices for the first element, and for every such choice there are $n-1$ choices for the second element. For every choice of elements $a_1$ and $a_2$, there are $n-2$ choices for the third element $a_3$, and so on, for a total of $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)$. This can be rewritten in various ways, for example as $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$. Your book may also use a "permutation" symbol.

(iii) I don't know what "contains only one ordered pair" means.

(iv) We can **choose** the $k$ elements in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways. For any such choice, there is only one way to line up the chosen elements in increasing order.

(v) I don't know what tools you have. We are counting the number of $k$-element **multisets**. Or else, equivalently, we are counting the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_n=k$, where $x_1$ is the number of $1$'s we choose, $x_2$ is the number of $2$'s, and so on. The standard way to solve this kind of problem is *Stars and Bars (please see Wikipedia). I would prefer not to write down an answer, but if you produce an answer I can tell you whether it is right.